# Create and save file with a custom content and name using VS Code API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We are developing a new VS Code extension in which we want to:

1. Create and open a new file in the VS Code editor with the provided
   content.
2. Save that file with a custom name without prompting to the user on a known path

Currently we're executing this via [VSCode API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace), but it is not fully serving the purpose as it's showing the "Save" dialog box to the user:

```js
workspace.openTextDocument({ content: yamlContent, language: "yaml" }).then(doc => {
    window.showTextDocument(doc);
    doc.save()
})
```

Also, a side question to confirm: Is there way to get relative file path for files outside workspace via [VSCode API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace)? (We're using [Node JS Path](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html) for this right now)

Comment: why don't you just do the file handling (create/write) in Node, no need to open editors

Comment: @rioV8 Consider this as a default config file which needs to be opened in editor for user review and allow any edits if user wants to before executing it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I implemented this to achieve the desired behavior:

```
await workspace.fs.writeFile(fileUri, new TextEncoder().encode(yamlContent));
window.showTextDocument(fileUri, { preview: false });
```